# How to best maintain a Redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We currently have an issue with our Redshift cluster in the sense that we're constantly always running out of space (we have to buy a new node every couple weeks) and query speeds for the same queries are declining.

Besides periodically running ANALYZE and VACUUM, what are some other options we have to better maintain our Redshift cluster?

Comment: Are you constantly adding significant amounts of new data?  Do you have a data retirement policy?  Have you sized for the amount of actively queried data you will have in the steady state (amount of data that will live on the cluster between arrival and retirement)?  If yes to these then please share

Comment: Or is this happening because of increasing query load which has some high-spill queries in it?  Or is it both?  Are there spikes of disk usage that you need to provision for or is it steady increases in data size?  I've seen many reasons for both disks filling up and speed reducing so more info will be needed to advise you on a course of action

Answer (score 1):

look at spectrum tables. you have to archive old data to s3 and create spectrum tables over it. adding new node every week is not a sustainable model and will fail.  we are regularly moving billions of records which are 2 months old to s3 and create spectrum tables over it. you have to pay only for the volume you have queried which is resonably low compare to new node. also as volume will increase performance will degrade. its better archive old data and keep recent queryable data only in the table.